# I there any way to restore scroll position on clicking of back button in ionic app perticularly on ios and safari

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi was working on ionic app i'm currently facing issue in ios ionic back button im not able to restore scrolled positon when click on back button let me know if anyone can suggest best solution?
i'm really fed up with the functionality some are supporting in android some are not supporting to make bug fixing taking to much time